# How do I show the topological space $([-a,a],\tau)$ is a Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology

I have started self studying topology, towards another course I would be taking next semester. I have been working through Munkres, Topology and had a question that I have been unable to work out on my own.

Consider the set $X=[-a,a]$ ( where $a \in \mathbb{R}$) where we define a subset $U \subseteq X$ to be open if $ 0 \notin U$ or if $U \supseteq (-a,a)$. Is $(X,\tau)$ a Hausdorff space ?  Intuitively, I think $X$  is a Hausdorff space but I have been unable to come up with a convincing argument for a proof.

I know that $X$ cannot be written as a union of two disjoint open subsets. Take $O_1,O_2 \in \tau$ such that $O_1 = [-a,0)$ and $O_2 = (0,a]$. But $O_1 \cup O_2 = X\setminus\{0\}$. Moreover, $X \in \tau$ is the only maximal subset  of $X$ that cannot be written as a union of disjoint subsets.

I donot know how to proceed from here. Would anyone be kind enough to help me with this problem ?

Comment: Don't give us your life story before the question. The first thing a reader needs to figure out is "can I help answer this question?" Your self-study of Munkres is noise in terms of figuring out whether someone can help you.

Comment: I apologise, I will refrain from doing that here after.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I disagree now.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think that this intro is helpful because it makes it so the question doesn't feel like someone is just looking for an answer to their homework but is actually interested in figuring the problem out.

Comment: I don't think the content of the intro is unhelpful, but it belongs after the question. I didn't say don't include the information, I said don't lead with it. @Gage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space being Hausdorff means that for any $2$ points $x_1,x_2$ (that are different) we can find disjoint open sets $O_1,O_2$ such that $O_1 \cap O_2 = \emptyset$ and $x_1 \in O_1$ and $x_2 \in O_2$. What happens if you choose $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 = b \in (-a,a)\backslash \{0\}$? What do the open sets that contain $0$ look like?

Comment: Oh! I see. The opens that contain 0 are precisely the sets that contain $(-a,a)$ as given in the problem statement. So, if I choose $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 = b \in (-a,a)\backslash \{0\}$ then the intersection is not empty. This would show $X$ is not Hausdorff. Thank you!

Comment: @Berci Thank you too!

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad I could help out.